# ios apple login Connecting information

Tags: ios, swift, apple-login

I am an Android developer.
While studying iOS development as a hobby, I got curious.
I'm trying to introduce Apple login, but I wonder if I can't get the CI value.
CI is called Connecting Information.
I'll be waiting for the reply. Thank you.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "CI"?  Is it a claim in the token you are looking for?

Comment: CI is called a personal identification number used in Korea.
It can be obtained through SNS login (Facebook, Kakao Talk (Korean messenger).
Do you have any related information?

Comment: I very much doubt that Apple would share this, even if they had it.  Sign In with Apple is a privacy protecting authentication service.

Comment: I'd like to ask you one question.
If the user has registered as a member in the normal way.
Can I check that this user has already registered as a member when he logged in to Apple?

Comment: You can request the user's email address the first time that they Sign In with Apple and you can then attempt to match that against email addresses for existing users.  The user may hide their real email address.

Comment: I'm sorry. I think I misrepresented the meaning.
User A registered with "temp@google.com".
User A logs in with Apple login later.(A's Apple account email is "exam@google.com")
So should A have two accounts?
Can't we find out that user A is already registered as a member?

Comment: How?  Maybe you could ask the user to link their accounts somehow but all you know about a Sign In with Apple user is the user identifier (and an email address if you requested it when they first sign in)